# Testing Backbone.js listenTo with jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm currently trying out jasmine to test our backbone.js app at work. One thing I have difficulty testing are event listeners set up using `listenTo`. Given a view like this:

```
class View extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @listenTo(@model, 'change', @render)
  render: ->
    # render the view
```

And a test like this:

```
# setup code for @model and @view skipped
describe "View", ->
  it "re-renders when the model changes", ->
    spyOn(@view, 'render')
    @model.set('some_attribute', 'value')
    expect(@view.render).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Obviously this test will fail, as we're not actually stubbing out render here. One solution I came up was to add another level of indirection:

```
listenTo: (other, event, callback_name) ->
  super(other, event, -> @[callback_name](arguments))
```

Then instead of passing a function to `listenTo` we pass a string (e.g. `@listenTo(@model, 'change', 'render')`) and now we can stub out `render`. But somehow that seems like a hack.

Is there a better solution to that problem? Or am I maybe writing tests at the wrong level of abstraction?

Comment: Just trying to understand this sentence, `Obviously this test will fail, as we're not actually stubbing out render here.`, could you please explain it ?

Comment: It will fail, because we're passing the actual implementation of `render` to `listenTo`. So when we stub `render` on the view it doesn't change what `listenTo` will call when the event is fired.

Comment: Aah okay, whether the method `render` was called or not, is the only thing that you need to verify, then would you like to replace the line `spyOn(@view, 'render');` with `spyOn(@view, 'render').andReturn();`, and give it a try ? It may not work though.

Comment: Which version of Jasmine do you use? `andReturn()` doesn't exist in 2.2 and `spyOn` never calls the original implementation by default.

Comment: I have used 1.3 and there were some situations where the original implementation was invoked for me, so I had started using `andReturn()`. And yes, I had a look at backbone code too, and you are right, `listenTo` stores the original callback function itself. So whatever I said is irrelevant for you :-/

Comment: Don't you have to attach your spies *before* instantiating your view? Once you `v = new View`, a reference to `v.render` is already hooked up to the event so the replacement spy won't be called. Don't you want to instrument the view's prototype *before* you create any instances? I'm sure the has come up before, do some searches on `[backbone.js] [jasmine]`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here? I mean, I know it's just an example, but it seems you're simply trying to test whether backbone's Events#listenTo works. There's no need. It works. Almost always when you encounter a situation like this, chances are you're trying to test something that doesn't need testing and your tests are in fact focused on implementation rather than functionality.

Comment: Yes, I realized that, too. I'm now testing that `listenTo` is called with the correct arguments instead.

Comment: @ujh am trying to understand why this is not working, is it because `listenTo` has a copy of `render` with has not been spied on ?

Comment: Exactly @Anenth, that's why it's not working. But testing that `listenTo` is called with the correct arguments seems like a better way to set this code anyway.

Comment: @ujh that's interesting, till now I believed that listeners will only have a reference to the function !. So listeners are quite heavy.

Comment: Well, they do. But they have a reference to the *actual* function you hand them as that's the way JavaScript works. Spying just replaces this function with a test double, but then it's already too late.